# How to filter only schools in GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-places-api

I am using GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController to search places in iOS. I write the name of place and get the results on basis of keyword. but the problem is that I want to search only school. So if I type any place name if it is school then I should appear in result else not.

**GMSAutocompleteFilter** just show few filters as establishment, region,city,address etc. but in android it is having filter as school

below is the code I am using for searching.

```
class SearchLocationController: DIBaseController {

    var resultsViewController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController?
    var searchController: UISearchController?
    var resultView: UITextView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        resultsViewController = GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController()
        resultsViewController?.delegate = self

        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsViewController)
        searchController?.searchResultsUpdater = resultsViewController

        let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
        filter.type = .establishment
        resultsViewController?.autocompleteFilter = filter

        // Put the search bar in the navigation bar.
        searchController?.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        navigationItem.titleView = searchController?.searchBar

        // When UISearchController presents the results view, present it in
        // this view controller, not one further up the chain.
        definesPresentationContext = true
        // Prevent the navigation bar from being hidden when searching.
        searchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    }
}

// Handle the user's selection.
extension SearchLocationController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewControllerDelegate {
    func resultsController(_ resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController,
                           didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
        searchController?.isActive = false
        // Do something with the selected place.

    }

    func resultsController(_ resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController,
                           didFailAutocompleteWithError error: Error){
        // TODO: handle the error.
        print("Error: ", error.localizedDescription)
    }

    // Turn the network activity indicator on and off again.
    func didRequestAutocompletePredictions(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    }

    func didUpdateAutocompletePredictions(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are using Places API then the type can be specified API request .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, in the iOS SDK, the supported places types are only `geocode`, `address`, `establishment`, `region` and `city`.

For more details, refer to [this](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/supported_types#table3).

Comment: Are you sure that in iOS sdk school is not supported ? If I have to use school in iOS sdk then how it is possible ?

Comment: That's what the provided link states.

Comment: That link does not define how do I use it with iOS ?

Comment: Do have a look at the url : https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/supported_types#table3 school is not a supported type in the current ios sdk